# One Regex to recognize years : Both 2008 and 08 need to be matched

Tags: regex

I'm currently using this regex to match years

```
^(19|20)\\d\\d[-,\\s,\\/]?(19|20)?\\d?\\d?
```

But this only matches years in its full format like `1988` but I need one which matches both `1988` as well as `08`.

Is this possible with a single regex?

Comment: Please explain why your regexp is so complicated just to match a year with the following format `yyyy`

Comment: Actually its also matching 1990-1991 or 1991-99 etc , since I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a ? after the `(19|20)`
?

like this?

```
^(19|20)?\\d\\d[-,\\s,\\/]?(19|20)?\\d?\\d?
```

Comment: This works thanks! But its also matching `000` as a year. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: What is your exact goal? Theoretically this should be enough for the year part: ^(19|20)?\\d\\d The following things catch the third zero. (And probably the original regex matched against 19000 also.)

Comment: Im getting a lot of mismatches . Things like `000`,` 60/23`,`122002`, `60%` are being matched as year.

Comment: Yes. The original regexp was too broad. Only for years this should be enough: ^(19|20)?\\d\\d$ I don't know what is your intention with the remaining part.

Comment: actually I wanted to match 1900-1911 as I needed it for the processing. Anyways thanks.

Comment: This: ^(19|20)?\\d\\d([-,\\s,\\/](19|20)?\\d\\d)?$ will match "year" and "year separator year" formats where year can be 88 or 1988 format. And the separators are coming from your original regexp.

Answer (score 2):

Just make the leading clause optional:

```
^(19|20)?\\d\\d[-,\\s,\\/]?(19|20)?\\d?\\d?
........^
```